# objective c audio player option

Tags: objective-c, avaudioplayer, ipod

i'm building an iphone application that base on playing some audio file. all thing are going ok but i need to add new  idea.i want to add slider, play and pause button similar to ipod.

play, pause, volume slider, and the most important on is the duration indicator with it's slider

Comment: Try to make your question more specific. What have you tried that doesn't work? What, specifically, are you having trouble understanding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most simple way is to use avTouch provided by Apple.